# GoogleApiClient em fragments

Tags: android-fragment, android-activity

O `app` em questão, tem uma atividade principal e dois fragmentos.

São dois painéis de informação, um contém a lista de endereços e outro apresenta um mapa mostrando os endereços da lista.

A lista é apresentada em um `RecyclerView`, composto de `cardviews` a cada endereço.

A inserção e atualização dos endereços ocorre em dois `fragment`s diferentes. Mas em ambos eu vou usar um `AutoCompleteTextView` e o Google Place API for Android, usando um objeto `GoogleApiClient`.

Não achei exemplos com fragmentos, somente usando a `activity`.

Estou seguindo este tutorial: [Android Places API: Autocomplete with getPlaceByID](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/)

Como eu faço pra usar isso dentro de um `fragment`? Onde o instanciamento do `GoogleApiClient` deve ser feito?

ATUALIZAÇÃO

Tentei seguir as dicas do Ack Lay, e fiz algum progresso, mas acabei me enrolando com os erros.

Ocorre que o meu código é um pouco diferente do exemplo. O campo, alias, campos, que vão receber as sugestões, não estão presentes durante o `onCreateView()` porque fazem parte de um form. que aparece ao clicar no FAB definido neste evento.

Note que já está funcionando com o `Google Places API Web Service`, que eu adaptei de outro tutorial. Posteriormente, li que ao invés de usar esta API, no Android, deve ser usada `Google Places API for Android` e esta é a razão da mudança.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerFragment";
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RunDbHelper runDbHelper;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
private OnOkButtonListener mCallback;
private CardView cardViewMessageIsEmpty;

public RecyclerFragment() {
    this.mCallback = null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
    cardViewMessageIsEmpty = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.emptyMessageCardView);
    runDbHelper = RunDbHelper.getInstance(getContext());
    List<RunData> mList = runDbHelper.getAllRuns();
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mList);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvRunList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Data entry dialog to add runs
            dialogInsertRun();
        }
    });

    cardViewMessageIsEmpty.setVisibility((mList == null || mList.isEmpty()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

public void dialogInsertRun() {
    // Get the Activity for layout inflater as this dialog runs inside a fragment
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View inflaterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_run, null);

    // Dialog Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder addRunDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    addRunDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_insert_run_title)
            .setView(inflaterView);

    // Data entry field objects
    final EditText runParcelEditText = (EditText) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.new_run_parcel);
    final AutoCompleteTextView collectAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.actv_new_collect_address);
    final EditText collectPersonEditText = (EditText) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.new_collect_person);
    final AutoCompleteTextView deliveryAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.actv_new_delivery_address);
    final EditText deliveryPersonEditText = (EditText) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.new_delivery_person);

    // Set directions into recyclerViewAdapter for autocomplete
    collectAddressACTV.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_new_run_autocomplete));
    deliveryAddressACTV.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_new_run_autocomplete));

    addRunDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            RunData runData = new RunData();

            runData.run_parcel = getStringOrEmpty(runParcelEditText);
            runData.collect_person = getStringOrEmpty(collectPersonEditText);
            runData.collect_address = getStringOrEmpty(collectAddressACTV);
            runData.delivery_person = getStringOrEmpty(deliveryPersonEditText);
            runData.delivery_address = getStringOrEmpty(deliveryAddressACTV);

            if (!(runData.collect_address.isEmpty() && runData.delivery_address.isEmpty())) {

                runData = runDbHelper.insertRun(runData, getActivity());
                if (runData != null) {
                    cardViewMessageIsEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), runDbHelper.getAllRuns());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    mCallback.addMarkersToMap(runData);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.dialog_insert_run_toast_nowhere, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    addRunDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    addRunDialog.create();
    addRunDialog.show();
}

private String getStringOrEmpty(EditText editText) {
    String mString = editText.getText().toString();
    mString = (mString == null || mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString);
    return mString;
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {

    if (context instanceof OnOkButtonListener) {
        mCallback = (OnOkButtonListener) context; // keep a reference to eula activity for interface
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + getString(R.string.exception_onokbutton_listener));
    }
    super.onAttach(context);
}

public void setCustomObjectListener(OnOkButtonListener listener) {
    this.mCallback = listener;
}

public interface OnOkButtonListener {
    void addMarkersToMap(RunData runData);
}
}
```

Os campos são `collectAddressACTV` e `deliveryAddressACTV` no método `dialogInsertRun()`

XML do diálogo

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_minimal_distance">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_new_run_parcel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_run_parcel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/collect_what"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_actv_new_collect_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/actv_new_collect_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/collect_where"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:maxLines="2"></AutoCompleteTextView>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_new_collect_person"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_collect_person"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/collect_who"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_actv_new_delivery_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/actv_new_delivery_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/delivery_where"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="2">

        </AutoCompleteTextView>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_new_delivery_person"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_delivery_person"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/delivery_who"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

E esta classe define o adaptador que para o autocomplete `Google Places API Web Service`. Ela é similar a classe do adaptador do link do tutorial que mencionei.

```
public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    // autocomplete code
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
    //------------ make your specific key ------------
    private static final String API_KEY = "AIza................................";

    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString(), getUserCountry(getContext()));

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input, String countryCode) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            stringBuilder
                    .append("?key=" + API_KEY)
                    .append("&components=country:" + countryCode)
                    .append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(stringBuilder.toString());

            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
//            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
//            Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    /**
     * Get ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code for this device (or null if not available)
     *
     * @param context Context reference to get the TelephonyManager instance from
     * @return country code or null
     */
    @Nullable
    public static String getUserCountry(Context context) {

        try {
            final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
            if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
                return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            } else if (tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
                String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
                if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                    return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
                }
            }
            String localeCountry = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
            if (localeCountry != null && localeCountry.length() == 2) {
                return localeCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que estava tudo errado, desde a pergunta. O problema não é porque o formulário que recebe as sugestões do `GoogleApiClient` esta em um fragmento, mas sim, porque está em um dialogo.

Foi preciso ajustar o local onde os objetos são declarados e instanciados para funcionar.

Depois, seguindo as dicas do @Ack-Lay, transformar em um `fragment` ficou fácil.

```
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment
        implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerFragment";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RunDbHelper runDbHelper;
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private OnOkButtonListener mCallback;
    private CardView cardViewMessageIsEmpty;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;

    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));

    public RecyclerFragment() {
        this.mCallback = null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();

        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);

        runDbHelper = RunDbHelper.getInstance(getContext());
        List<RunData> mList = runDbHelper.getAllRuns();
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mList);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvRunList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Data entry dialog to add runs
                dialogInsertRun();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void dialogInsertRun() {

        // Get the Activity for layout inflater as this dialog runs inside a fragment
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_run, null);

        // Dialog Builder
        AlertDialog.Builder addRunDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        addRunDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_insert_run_title)
                .setView(view);

        // Data entry field objects
        final EditText runParcelEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.new_run_parcel);
        final AutoCompleteTextView collectAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actv_new_collect_address);
        final EditText collectPersonEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.new_collect_person);
        final AutoCompleteTextView deliveryAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actv_new_delivery_address);
        final EditText deliveryPersonEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.new_delivery_person);

        collectAddressACTV.setThreshold(3);
        collectAddressACTV.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        collectAddressACTV.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

        deliveryAddressACTV.setThreshold(3);
        deliveryAddressACTV.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        deliveryAddressACTV.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

        addRunDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                RunData runData = new RunData();

                runData.run_parcel = getStringOrEmpty(runParcelEditText);
                runData.collect_person = getStringOrEmpty(collectPersonEditText);
                runData.collect_address = getStringOrEmpty(collectAddressACTV);
                runData.delivery_person = getStringOrEmpty(deliveryPersonEditText);
                runData.delivery_address = getStringOrEmpty(deliveryAddressACTV);

                if (!(runData.collect_address.isEmpty() && runData.delivery_address.isEmpty())) {

                    runData = runDbHelper.insertRun(runData, getActivity());
                    if (runData != null) {
                        cardViewMessageIsEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), runDbHelper.getAllRuns());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                        mCallback.addMarkersToMap(runData);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.dialog_insert_run_toast_nowhere, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        addRunDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        addRunDialog.create();
        addRunDialog.show();
    }

    private String getStringOrEmpty(EditText editText) {
        String mString = editText.getText().toString();
        mString = (mString == null || mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString);
        return mString;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {

        if (context instanceof OnOkButtonListener) {
            mCallback = (OnOkButtonListener) context; // keep a reference to eula activity for interface
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + getString(R.string.exception_onokbutton_listener));
        }
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public void setCustomObjectListener(OnOkButtonListener listener) {
        this.mCallback = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(TAG, "Google Places API connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }

    public interface OnOkButtonListener {
        void addMarkersToMap(RunData runData);
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Como eu faço pra usar isso dentro de um fragment?

Basta seguir as alterações abaixo.

No `Fragment` você vai apenas alterar onde tiver `this` para `getActivity()`. Outra alteração será nas suas views, pois ao invés de usar `findViewById(R.id...)` vai acrescentar o `view` ficando desta forma `view.findViewById(R.id...)`. Exemplo:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container);

    ....
    mPhoneTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    ....

    return view;
}
```

Desta forma na sua `MainActivity`, terá que chamar seu `Fragment`:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MeuFragment())
                .commit();
```

> Onde o instanciamento do GoogleApiClient deve ser feito?

Assim como a `Activity`, o `Fragment` possui um [ciclo de vida](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=pt-br#Lifecycle) e um tratamento de armazenamento de estado, que é iniciado no momento que o `Fragment` é atrelado a `Activity`, e não necessariamente está visível na tela. Sendo assim utiliza-se o mesmo processo que é feito em uma *activity*.

Veja como ficou a alteração do código no qual [coloquei no **IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/Mf0rtG).

Comment: To entendendo e mexendo aqui, mas o campo autocomplete fica em um dialogo que não está aberto no oncreateview(). Tentei adaptar o codigo de diversas maneiras, mas acabei encontrando uns erros que não consegui resolver. Vou modificar a pergunta, acrescentando o codigo e alguns comentários.

Comment: @ReneFreak é no mesmo contexto, independente se é em um dialogo, etc. Vai seguir a mesma linha de raciocínio. Qual erro que não conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Foram diversos erros, que fui eliminando, até um erro no método onConnected(). Ao tentar debugar, acabou gerando erros no outro fragment que não estava nem mexendo.  Coloquei o codigo na pergunta. Espero que ajude a resolver. Vlw

Comment: Qual nome do erro?! O erro esta nessa classe? Voocê tem que aponta-los senão não da pra resolver.

Comment: @ReneFreak coloque o XML do seu Dialog para eu verificar aqui o que pode ser o erro.

Comment: Postei. Note que esta classe está funcionando com o web service. Meu objetivo agora é transforma-la de forma a usar o API correto.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52772/discussion-between-ack-lay-and-rene-freak).

Comment: @ReneFreak no dialogo aparentemente não aconteceu nada de erro. Porém não faço ideia o que você está fazendo aqui: collectAddressACTV.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_new_run_autocomplete));

Comment: GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter é o adaptador do API. Coloquei o codigo pra que possa ver a classe, mas é similar ao do link do tutorial.